# How to stop people using coal as fuel in their houses?

Tags: banished

People take firewood and also coal to use it in their houses during winter. I would like to use coal only for production of better tools, not for houses. Is there a way to stop people take coal from storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no way to prevent people from doing this. The best way to ensure that it does get used for tools is to put your blacksmith right next to the stockpile nearest the mine, however its still not going to be that helpful.

You can also sell your excess firewood to a trader for coal, which should create a big enough surplus to let your toolsmiths work a while.

Answer (score 5):

The best trick I have found is to put my coal mine next to a stockpile, away from the actual village. Then ensure that there is always enough firewood in the stockpile inside your village and do not place any markets.

This will cause the villagers to go looking for something to heat their home with, and they always seem to grab the first source near their home. On the flip side, the miner will try to deposit their coal in the closest stockpile from their work.

This ensures that villagers will have to settle for firewood, because the coal is too far away for them to bother with. It is however very important that you do not have any markets, else the plan will not work nearly as well: the market traders will go through the entire map to gather resources of every type, which includes coal, which will then rapidly get eaten up by villagers using the market.

Comment: This is a bad plan because it requires that you don't place any markets at all. If you don't build any markets, then your villagers will not eat healthy food properly, will hoard food and wood, and will have to spend valuable time walking to the storehouses when they should be doing their own jobs.

Comment: Hopefully an update will bring the option to specify which items to stock in a market :p This would be the perfect solution otherwise.